# Bind ViewModel command to MvxCollectionViewCell

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm working on MvvxCross clone of iOS AppStore

[image]

and I want to bind click on an individual app cell to my ViewModel command.

Does anyone can point me to a sample of code how this can be done?

Here is the source code of the clone app
https://github.com/L3xer/MvvmCross-AppStore